# Really long integer string to int conversion

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am getting this value from Google Drive API as drive size.

16106127360

How can i convert that string to an int/long/unsigned in c++ Builder.

1. StrToInt() cant, it say invalid integer.
2. atol() also fails, it returns garbled value
3. atoll() ? I cant seems to use that function in c++ Builder

Also what numeric  data type of C++ builder can hold the value 16106127360 ?

thanks

Comment: It's likely you're compiling for a system with a 32-bit `long`. Use an explicitly sized type like `uint64_t` to store a number that large.

Comment: [`std::stoul()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) should work well.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/488/stdstring/9741/conversion-to-integers-floating-point-types#t=201608091915487151323

Comment: "16106127360" is not a "really long" integer string.  I was expecting to see something like: 135066410865995223349603216278805969938881475605667027524485143851526510604859533833940287150571909441798207282164471551373680419703964191743046496589274256239341020864383202110372958725762358509643110564073501508187510676594629205563685529475213500852879416377328533906109750544334999811150056977236890927563

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`16106127360` is too large to fit in a 32bit (`unsigned`) `int` <sup>1</sup>.  That value requires a 64bit (`unsigned`) `__int64` or (`unsigned`) `long long` instead.

There are quite a number of different ways you can convert such a string value to a 64bit integer variable:

- There are `StrToInt64()`, `StrToInt64Def()`, and `TryStrToInt64()` functions for `__int64` values in the `SysUtils.hpp` header:

  ```
  __int64 size = StrToInt64("16106127360");
  ```

  ```
  __int64 size = StrToInt64Def("16106127360", -1);
  ```

  ```
  __int64 size;
  if (TryStrToInt64("16106127360", size)) ...
  ```

  (in modern C++Builder versions, there are also corresponding `UInt64` functions for `unsigned __int64` values as well)
- There are `strtoll()`/`wcstoll()` functions in the `stdlib.h` header:

  ```
  long long size = strtoll("16106127360");
  ```

  ```
  long long size = wcstoll(L"16106127360");
  ```
- there are `sscanf` functions in the `stdio.h` header. Use the `%lld` or `%llu` format specifiers:

  ```
  long long size;
  sscanf("16106127360", "%lld", &size);
  ```

  ```
  unsigned long long size;
  sscanf("16106127360", "%llu", &size);
  ```

  ```
  long long size;
  swscanf(L"16106127360", L"%lld", &size);
  ```

  ```
  unsigned long long size;
  swscanf(L"16106127360", L"%llu", &size);
  ```
- you can use `std::istringstream` or `std::wistringstream` in the `sstream` header:

  ```
  std::istringstream iis("16106127360");
  __int64 size; // or unsigned
  iis >> size;
  ```

  ```
  std::wistringstream iis(L"16106127360");
  __int64 size; // or unsigned
  iis >> size;
  ```

<sup>1</sup>: (if you are compiling your C++Builder project for iOS 9, `long` is 64bit, otherwise it is 32bit on every other supported platform)

Comment: Perfect for c++ builder, thatnks everyone

Answer (score 4):

See [this runnable program](http://cpp.sh/5svol)

This code, using stringstream, should work:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string ss = "16106127360";
    std::stringstream in;
    in << ss;
    long long num;
    in >> num;
}
```

Comment: check out this: http://cpp.sh/7mt6w it doesn't work for really large string / integers